# How to sparge with a inner mash cylinder?

Tags: equipment, sparge, kettle

I have bought a BeerMaker 30  and now I wonder how to do the sparging so that I get the clearest wort possible.

[image: BeerMaker 30]

The issue for me is, that I have a steel cylinder that goes into my electric mash/brew kettle. The bottom of the cylinder i a metal plate with holes in it. I suspect that while I do the mashing, some particles will get through there and end up in the brew kettle.

When I am done with mashing, and start sparging I will have a hard time getting all the particles out, since a Vorlauf would be the whole liquid volume.

I am thinking about getting a mash-bag that I could put on the inside of the steel cylinder (or even on the outside).

Am I thinking too complicated? Is this effort really necessary? How would you use this?

I have not yet used this, but I hope to avoid errors that are unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just treat it like any other mash tun.  Before you pull that thing out of the kettle start drawing off wort through the valve at the base (at least it looks like a valve in the picture).  Collect it in a pitcher that you can easily pour from.  Then slowly pour in back in at the top of the cylinder.  Do this repeatedly until you think the wort looks clear enough.  It may take 2-4L of circulation total.

Keep in mind that the wort won't look like clear beer though.  It will be cloudy.  What you are looking for is that there are no big pieces of grain or husk still coming out.  You'll be able to see them as you pour from the pitcher back in.

Good luck